# Redirect user to different thank-you pages based on choice selected in dropdown in form fields of contact form 7 (3 choices to 3 thank-you pages)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a dropdown field in my form. I want the user to get redirected to different thank you pages when the user submits a form. The redirection should be based on choices selected in the dropdown form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. It worked for me. :)

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
if ( '111' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {

  var lpLocation =  document.getElementById("lp-location").value;

  if (lpLocation == "choice1") {
    location = 'http://example.com/';
  } else if (lpLocation == "choice2") {
    location = 'http://google.com/';
  }

}
}, false )
```

In the second line, 111 is the form ID. I have multiple forms and only need this to work on one of them.

On the next line, “lp-location” is the ID for my select field. So my form tag looks like this:

```
 [select* location id:lp-location include_blank "choice1" "choice2"]
```